# Access buttons that were created in a loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, button, actionlistener

I've created a board with many buttons e.g. 900+. Since this is a lot of work I thought I'll do it in an loop. But now I want to add an ActionListener to each of those buttons that will give for the button in row i and column j the arrary number[i][j] the value 1. I don't see any way to do this without making it button by button. I'm already looking forward to your answers. Here my Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class MakeMotive {
    int howManyButtonsVer = 34; 
    int howManyButtonsHor = 27;
    int sideLength = 50; 
    int [][] number = new int [howManyButtonsHor+1][howManyButtonsVer+1];
    JButton[][] button = new JButton [howManyButtonsHor+1][howManyButtonsVer+1]; 
    private JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  try {
                       MakeMotive window = new MakeMotive();
                       window.frame.setVisible(true);
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                                         e.printStackTrace();
                                         }
        }
    });
}

public MakeMotive(){
    frame = new JFrame("Menu");
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    for(int i = 0; i<=howManyButtonsHor; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j<=howManyButtonsVer; j++){
           button[i][j] = new JButton();
           button[i][j].setBounds(sideLength*i, sideLength*j, sideLength,sideLength );
           button[i][j].setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.PLAIN, 10));
           button[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);
           button[i][j].setText(i+"a"+j);
           frame.getContentPane().add(button[i][j]);
           button[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                            }
            });
       }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Declare the `JButton[][] button` in the field instead of the constructor

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this code:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MakeMotive {
    private static int howManyButtonsVer = 34;
    private static int howManyButtonsHor = 27;
    private static int sideLength = 50;
    private int[][] number = new int[howManyButtonsHor + 1][howManyButtonsVer + 1];
    private JButton[][] button = new JButton[howManyButtonsHor + 1][howManyButtonsVer + 1];
    private JFrame frame;

    private MakeMotive() {
        frame = new JFrame("Menu");
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        MyActionListener myActionListener = new MyActionListener(this); // one action listener
        for (int i = 0; i <= howManyButtonsHor; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= howManyButtonsVer; j++) {
                button[i][j] = new MyButton(i, j); // create your own button, that knows its location
                button[i][j].setBounds(sideLength * i, sideLength * j, sideLength, sideLength);
                button[i][j].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
                button[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);
                button[i][j].setText(i + "a" + j);
                frame.getContentPane().add(button[i][j]);
                button[i][j].addActionListener(myActionListener); // add the one listener to all buttons
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                MakeMotive window = new MakeMotive();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private void markValue(int i, int j) {
        number[i][j] = 1;
    }

    private final static class MyButton extends JButton {
        private final int i;
        private final int j;

        MyButton(int i, int j) {
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
        }
    }

    private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
        private MakeMotive makeMotive;

        MyActionListener(MakeMotive makeMotive) {
            this.makeMotive = makeMotive;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MyButton source = (MyButton) e.getSource(); // its your own button
            makeMotive.markValue(source.i, source.j);   // get the location and mark the array position
        }
    }
}
```

There you have your own button class that saves its location variables and one single action listener that asks the event source (your button) about his location and saves it in the number array.

You could also remove the number array completely and give your button a variable "selected".